# What happens to the Session in @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, transactions

Hi I have been chasing an error in my office code since a week now. It relates to Spring, Hibernate and Transactions.

What I know:
1. Lazy Loading.
2. How Spring uses proxies and interceptor for its Transaction management.
3. Transaction propagation in Spring and that our code uses the default REQUIRED.
4. Session per request/conversation and the detached entity fundamentals of Hibernate to keep the session and the fact that ours is not session per conversation.

My scenario:
A method in my code (written by someone else) uses @Transactional (- call it method a()) and calls another service method that loads a customer from DB using Hibernate (- call it method b()). b() also has @Transactional on it. Customer has many Lazy fields and by the time the control comes back to method a() - the lazy fields can't be loaded because the session is closed. What I don't understand is - why was the session closed when method a() has not yet finished? What does Spring do with the session when b() finishes? I don't mind being pointed to a web address.

I have more questions because I am messing around with this for a week now but wouldn't like to dirty this post without understanding what's going on with the session.

Please suggest.

Comment: Do these two methods use different transaction managers?

Comment: Unfortunately not. At least that's what I can tell from the configuration but is there a solid way to confirm that?

Comment: I just added a method c() after the call to b() finishes and used sessFactory.getCurrentSession() in it to reattach the customer and initialize the lazy fields and it worked - no more lazy exceptions but my question remains - why was the session closed on return from b()?

Comment: I can imagine the following reasons: the propagation is in fact REQUIRES_NEW, or the tx manager is different, or the method b() doesn't get the current session but initializes another one, or method b() is in fact called in a separate thread from the thread calling a(). Without seeing any line of code, it's quite hard to answer.

Comment: I will recheck all of that by printing thread names, explicitly using REQUIRED and making sure no open session is used and get back accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The threads are same and also made sure no openSession and only getCurrentSession() is used. I am getting more and more confused. Because in method a() sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() gives me an error that no current session is bound to the thread (shouldn't I get one here as I have Transactional annotation on method a()) but if I write another method c() called from a() after the call to b() and do sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() from c() it gives me the current session (c() has Transactional annotation too). What's going on here?

Comment: Based on the comment above is a() giving me the error because currentSession is bound to the a different context say the JTATransaction is read from a different context say the running Thread? I am so confused :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep @Transactional at your Service method. Make getXXX() calls to load the lazy properties on return entity object from the same service method a(). There is another cool option. Hibernate Fetch Profiles. Define Fetch Profile at Entity and set it active from your service or dao.